# Android service isn't working

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, android-service

I cant start my android service. I want to call it in my fragment but its not working and doesn't show any error.

Here is my fragment class. I am trying to start service with this code:

`Activity.StartService(new Intent(Activity, typeof(SimpleStartedService)));`

My Fragment's code:

```
class SettingsFragment : Fragment
{
    public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public static Settings NewInstance()
    {
        var settings = new Settings { Arguments = new Bundle() };
        return settings;
    }

    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        var ignored = base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.settings, null);

        var btnStartService = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnStartService);

        btnStartService.Click += delegate
        {
            Activity.StartService(new Intent(Activity, typeof(SimpleStartedService)));
        };

        return view;
    }
}
```

Here is the my service. program is not entering here.

```
[Service]
public class SimpleStartedService : Service
{
    static readonly string TAG = "X:" + typeof(SimpleStartedService).Name;
    static readonly int TimerWait = 4000;
    Timer timer;
    DateTime startTime;
    bool isStarted = false;

    public override void OnCreate()
    {
        base.OnCreate();
    }

    public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
    {
        Log.Debug(TAG, $"OnStartCommand called at {startTime}, flags={flags}, startid={startId}");
        if (isStarted)
        {
            TimeSpan runtime = DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(startTime);
            Log.Debug(TAG, $"This service was already started, it's been running for {runtime:c}.");
        }
        else
        {
            startTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
            Log.Debug(TAG, $"Starting the service, at {startTime}.");
            timer = new Timer(HandleTimerCallback, startTime, 0, TimerWait);
            isStarted = true;
        }
        return StartCommandResult.NotSticky;
    }

    public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
    {
        // This is a started service, not a bound service, so we just return null.
        return null;
    }


    public override void OnDestroy()
    {           
        timer.Dispose();
        timer = null;
        isStarted = false;

        TimeSpan runtime = DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(startTime);
        Log.Debug(TAG, $"Simple Service destroyed at {DateTime.UtcNow} after running for {runtime:c}.");
        base.OnDestroy();
    }

    void HandleTimerCallback(object state)
    {
        TimeSpan runTime = DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(startTime);
        Log.Debug(TAG, $"This service has been running for {runTime:c} (since ${state})." );
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you added an entry to the manifest?

Comment: yes but still not working

Comment: Post your manifest as well.

Comment: <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:theme="@style/MyTheme">
    <service android:enabled="true" android:name="Service_Example.Service_Example.SimpleStartedService" />
  </application>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The declaration in Manifest File must be correct:

```
<service android:enabled="true" android:name="<PACKAGE_NAME_HERE.SERVICE_CLASS_NAME_HERE>" />
```

Also, check for Upper case and Lowercaseleeters in name, it must be same in both places.

Comment: @Likya07 try clean build then. If still doesn't then uninstall the app from device as well.

Comment: @Sufian i clean build and uninstall the app and know it is working thank you